# How to turn a string column into numeric and save string values as labels not to lose information in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, label

I would like to convert a string column into numeric to facilitate calculation, but I would also like to preserve the information of the values. Thus, I would like to assign the string values as labels. Not sure if people do this in R, but it was common practice in Stata, so whenever you pulled a table or plotted a graph you could see the labels instead of assigned numbers. The problem that I have is that there are more than 20 string values, and more than 10k rows. So, let's say I have the following dataframe:

```
df <- data.frame(color = c("green", "green", "blue", "red", "green", "blue", "red"))
df
  color
1 green
2 green
3  blue
4   red
5 green
6  blue
7   red
```

How can I assign one number for each color, save the string information, and assign it as value labels?

Comment: `factor` is R's class for categorical data. `df$color_factor = factor(df$color)`. It's a bit different from Stata - it will still display as the color names, but internally each unique value will be assigned to an integer, and you can access those integers with `as.integer(df$color_factor)`. You can also specify an ordering for the "levels" - the default will be alphabetical, e.g., `df$color_factor = factor(df$color, levels = c("red", "green", "blue"))` to override the alpha order. Where you go from there will depend on what you want to do to "facilitate calculation".

Comment: This may be of interest: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3445316/factors-in-r-more-than-an-annoyance

Comment: Thank you so much Gregor! For now, I am just doing some descriptive statistics and exploring the data, but later I may run regressions and do an in-depth analysis.

Comment: Thank you, jpsmith. It sure is of interest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31707654/r-set-duplicate-row-names-to-a-numeric-data-frame)

I am afraid you cannot have duplicate row names in a data.frame in R. You might want to use a factor instead if you have repeated strings. The next example produces a bar plot with the labels using this approach.

```
library(tidyverse)

df |> 
  mutate(color = factor(color)) |> 
  ggplot(aes(x = color)) +
  geom_bar()
```

Comment: Thank you so much Juan! You got a step ahead of my question, but that's one of the main reasons I wanted to label my data!!!